# keydown event only works after any other key is pressed

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am developing a Mozilla add-on which replaces the number keys on left side with their shift +  equivalents. For example if you press 1 it will be replaced by '!' automatically(specially for online compilers). Here is the code

```
document.activeElement.addEventListener("keydown",keyc);
var ch = [')','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','('];
function keyc(event)
{
    var x = document.activeElement.value;
    if( event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            x= x + ch[event.keyCode -48];
        }
    document.activeElement.value = x ;
}
```

This works fine but the character is replaced only when another key is pressed after the number key.
Can anyone point out as to why that might be happening...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using the keydown event. It fires before the input is entered into the field. If you instead use the keyup event it will fire when the input actually is entered into the input field.

UPDATE:

Ok so I updated my answer with the following corrections. I block the input by preventing the default behaviour of the keydown event. And I insert the character at the caret position instead of appending it to the end of the textarea.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4VaY/6/

```
document.activeElement.addEventListener("keydown",blockInput);
document.activeElement.addEventListener("keyup",keyc);

var ch = [')','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','('];
function keyc(event)
{
    var txtArea = document.activeElement;
    var x = txtArea.value;
    if( event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
        {
            insertAtCaret(txtArea, ch[event.keyCode -48]);
        }
}

function blockInput(event){
    if( event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
    {
        event.preventDefault();   
    }
}

function insertAtCaret(txtarea,text) {
    var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
    var strPos = 0;
    var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
        "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        strPos = range.text.length;
    }
    else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
    var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
    txtarea.value=front+text+back;
    strPos = strPos + text.length;
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
        range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (br == "ff") {
        txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
        txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
        txtarea.focus();
    }
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Nice point. So the docuemnt.activeElement.value is not updated till after keyup

Comment: It works fine except on ideone.com. On ideone.com the the problem persists but now when the key 1 is pressed and any other key is pressed after it the input is "1!<other keychar>".
Could it be that any script from ideone is interfering with it?

Comment: @user3364905 have you used my script? Since it is the keyup event we are now using you have to remove the last character manually. That is why I included the line ``x = x.substring(0, x.length - 1);``.

Comment: @Kristian Barrett I did use it and it worked perfectly on JSFiddle but it raises two issues 
 1> it doesn't work if the key is kept pressed(not the real problem). 
2> When I used it in my add-on it works except when I edit some code in the middle. (automatically takes the cursor to the end of text and special characters appear at end of text.)

Comment: @user3364905 Ok I have updated my answer and I hope it fixes the issues you had. Let me know what you think.